# <frame> Tag Alternative - HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to use some frames to split a page into various parts and then load external content into each frame. I have noted that frames are deprecated in HTML5, what would be my alternative if this is the case?

Ideally I want to be able to load a frame from clicking the button, then when the frame is in place I want the user to be able to set the size and then load the content. Is this possible using a HTML5 frame replacement?

Many thanks

JS

```
<script>
var frame;
function addFrame() {
    frame = document.createElement('iframe');
  frame.height = "200px";
  frame.width = "200px";
  frame.setAttribute('id', 'superFrame');
  document.body.appendChild(frame);
}
function loadGoogle(){
    frame.setAttribute('src','https://www.google.com')
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<button onClick="addFrame();">
Add Frame
</button>
<br>
<br>
<button onClick="loadGoogle();">
Load URL
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note, that the `<frame>` element is deprecated, not the `<iframe>` element. It seems, that's exactly what you're using anyway.

Comment: Don't confuse *iframes* with *framesets*. The code you show uses an `<iframe>` tag *inside the page*, which AFAIK is not deprecated. The deprecated feature is using the `<frameset>` and `<frame>` tags to layout *the entire page*. However, consider the reasons *why* the feature is deprecated: it make it much harder to handle bookmarks, the browser's back and forward buttons, and accessbility (e.g. screen readers).

Comment: Okay, I am going to move away from iframes to webviews, its more the layout I was wanting to know about. In HTML4 you can have a frame that the user can manipulate to set the size etc... would I have to use CSS to do this in HTML5?

Comment: If you really don't need that much separation and you are in control of other resources then use `div` and load content via `AJAX`.

Comment: Xaqron - Thank you, I will look at this option.